# Publishing release notes as part of a VSTS realise definition

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, wiki, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have release definition that publishes a web app and database. As part pic that definition I am generating release notes into a .md file and manually uploading them to the projects wiki page on VSTS. I was wondering if there was a way to add a task to the release definition to automate the publishing of the release notes to the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each team project wiki employs a git repository backend, you can clone that wiki repository and add or edit pages, then commit and push changes.

[Clone and update wiki pages offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiki-update-offline)

The simple way:

1. Check **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option in the Phase of build
2. Add Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@xxx.visualstudio.com/xxxx mywiki`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`)
3. Add tasks to add or modify pages
4. Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `config --global user.email "test@example.com"`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\mywiki`)
5. Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `config --global user.name "tester"`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\mywiki`)
6. Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Aguments: `add *`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\mywiki`)
7. Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Aguments: `commit -m "update wikipage"`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\mywiki`)
8. Command Line task (Tool: `git`; Aguments: `push https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@xx.visualstudio.com/xxx`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\mywiki`)

You can put the commands of step 3 ~ 7 in a file (e.g. bat, ps1), then just add a task and specify the file.

Note: The **Project Collection Build Service account** needs **Contribute** permission (Version Control admin page and set permission for Git repositories)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a ps1 file that will clone and add new pages and do some clean-up. Is your way still possible if using the Hosted VS2017 build agent i.e. an when hosted by Microsoft and not me

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. I was having issues with username and password which is now resolved.

Comment: @psycho can you share the details? I would like to have the same.